# Rows and columns of the one-step transition probability matrix

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix, discrete-time

I am currently studying the textbook *Introduction to Modeling and Analysis of Stochastic Systems, Second Edition*, by V. G. Kulkarni. In a section on **discrete-time Markov chains**, the author introduces the **one-step transition probability matrix** as follows:

> $$P = \begin{bmatrix} p_{1, 1} & p_{1, 2} & p_{1, 3} & \dots & p_{1, N} \\ p_{2, 1} & p_{2, 2} & p_{2, 3} & \dots & p_{2, N} \\ p_{3, 1} & p_{3, 2} & p_{3, 3} & \dots & p_{3, N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ p_{N, 1} & p_{N, 2} & p_{N, 3} & \dots & p_{N, N}  \end{bmatrix} \tag{2.4}$$
>
> The matrix $P$ in the equation above is called the *one-step transition probability matrix*, or transition matrix for short, of the DTMC. Note that the rows correspond to the starting state and the columns correspond to the ending state of a transition.

I'm not sure what the author means by the following:

> ... the rows correspond to the starting state and the columns correspond to the ending state of a transition.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+transition+matrix for links to many examples here on CV. [Focusing on upvoted posts with answers,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+transition+matrix+score%3A1+answers%3A1) I found a good (albeit brief) answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/246865/919. Following that in the list are many clear, simple examples.

Comment: @whuber eh, are you sure this answers my question? My question seems relatively simple, and I don’t see how that answer addresses it.

Comment: I haven't claimed it does: I am *asking* whether the top hits in those searches answer the question (well, maybe even *suggesting* they ought to).  I do hope that by reviewing them you will get closer to understanding this concept.

Comment: @whuber oh, ok. I’ve looked through several of them, and they’re all relatively complex questions and answers compared to the very simple question I’m asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just saying that the probability of ending in state $j$, given that you start in state $i$ is the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column of the matrix.  For example, if you start in  state $3$, the probability of transitioning to state $7$ is the element in the 3rd row, and 7th column of the matrix: $p_{37}$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.